# Error 405 when trying to do POST, PUT, and DELETE

Tags: angular, http, typescript, html-table, angular-http

i'm trying to using an API from json blob and then when i try using POST, PUT, and DELETE methods i got an error like this: `DELETE https://jsonblob.com/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b68637 405 ()`.

Here is the json blob [link](https://jsonblob.com/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b6863)

```js
 //request
    getStocksAPI(): Observable<any>
    {
        //return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/Student/") //perhatikan port localhost
        return this.http.get("https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonblob/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b6863")
        .map( (res: Response) => res.json() )
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    }
    //end of request

 
 //add
    addStudent(newId: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newMajor: string, newScore: string, newEmail: string): Observable<any>
    {
        //return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/Student/", {id: newId, name: newName, year: newYear, semester: newSemester, major: newMajor, score: newScore, email: newEmail});
        return this.http.post("https://jsonblob.com/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b6863", {id: newId, name: newName, year: newYear, semester: newSemester, major: newMajor, score: newScore, email: newEmail});
    }
    //end of add
 
 //update
 updStudent(Id: string, newName: string, newYear: string, newSemester: string, newMajor: string, newScore: string, newEmail: string): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.http.put("https://jsonblob.com/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b6863"+Id,
            {
                Id: Id,
                name: newName, 
                year: newYear,
                semester: newSemester,
                major: newMajor,
                score: newScore,
                email: newEmail
            });
             
        // return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/Student/"+Id,
        // {
        //     Id: Id,
        //     name: newName, 
        //     year: newYear,
        //     semester: newSemester,
        //     major: newMajor,
        //     score: newScore,
        //     email: newEmail
        // });
     }
     //end of update
  
 //delete
    delStudent(id: string): Observable<any>
    {
        //return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/Student/" +id);
        return this.http.delete("https://jsonblob.com/fbd3fa51-c4fe-11e7-96cf-e300ee4b6863"+id);
    }
    //end of delete
```

Before trying json blob's API the CRUD operations are working correctly using json-server `localhost:3000`. After using API only GET method that work. The POST, PUT, and DELETE give me error 405.
Can anyone help me solve this error?

Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing `/api/jsonBlob` part in `POST` request url.

Comment: [The documentation says](https://jsonblob.com/api) `DELETE /api/jsonBlob/<blobId>` but you seem to have `DELETE /api/jsonBlob/<blobId>Id`. Get rid of the `+Id` at the end of the URL string. I also think you are fundamentally misunderstanding the API - it stores only a single JSON blob (one student in your case) at the `<blobId>`.